# Lost control of the windows sent to monitor on HDMI, which xrandr doesn’t detect

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi

I have set two monitors—one is a usual monitor, and the second one is an HDMI TV.
The configuration is done in a single [xorg.conf](http://pastie.org/pastes/9113030/text/) file.

The problem is that the second display seem to be working, i.e. it shows my wallpaper after I start the computer, I can put windows there by specifying `DISPLAY=:0.1`, I do run mpv on the TV this way, sound over HDMI works fine as well. But I lose control of the window since it has been sent to the TV. If I open a terminal and run mpv from there, like

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 mpv --profile=hdmi file.mkv
```

it runs window on TV, passes sound to TV, but any input to the terminal is ignored—I cannot set player on pause or rewind. The keys in my window manager that must switch focus to another screen also not seem to be working, I can move mouse over the other screen, but RMB (that should set mpv on pause) doesn’t work, too. So I’ve checked `xrandr` output and… it [told](http://pastie.org/pastes/9113032/text/) me that I don’t even have the HDMI connected. However, `nvidia-settings` shows my dual monitor setup properly.

[image: shows]

Now about configuration:

- It’s Gentoo amd64, kernel 3.12;
- Xorg 1.14.3;
- xrandr program version 1.4.1;
- Server reports RandR version 1.4;
- nvidia-drivers 331.20;
- It is a desktop with a discrete video card GF 550Ti, not a laptop.

Comment: You've configured two different X screens, instead of one screen across both monitors. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I see no point in spanning one screen to two monitors. Also as you might have noticed, they’re of different size. Yes, this is what I intended and it worked till I recently noticed this bug. Sorry for my English.